# .NET - JSON Data - Deserialization - Lists & Dictionaries

Tags: .net, json, list, serialization, dictionary

I need to pull back from a database JSON documents that are not based on a standard object.

Is there a way using .NET to "deserialize" these documents into Lists & Dictionaries of primitive objects (string, int, bool, etc...)

Any library that can do this in both directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .NET 3.5 Framework you can use [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). Using the Deserialize method will return an object which you can cast to a Dictionary type or Object[] depending on what's in the JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

The [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) library can serialize to and from `Dictionary<string, string>`, although I don't know if it can deserialize *lists* of dictionaries. I was trying to figure that out when I came across this question :)